# Using Apache Velocity (with SparkJava) with loaded templates

Tags: jquery, html, velocity, spark-java, apache-velocity

I am building a website using Spark + Velocity. This has HTML components that are very similar across the webpages of the site, so I have put my shared components in some templates that I dynamically load into the page.

To give you a simple example, I have pages such as this:

**anyPage.vm**

```
<head> stuff in here </head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
$AJavaObject.ToString() # <-- using the Velocity templating language
...
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
         $("#header").load("header.vm");
    }
</script>
```

This works all right, except for the fact that the Velocity code inside `header.vm` won't work.

**header.vm**

```
<h1>Header</h1>
$AnotherJavaObject.toString()
```

The **header.vm** does not contain any `<head>` or `<body>` tagging.

When rendering the page, instead of seeing the string representation of the `AnotherJavaObject`, I see the actual string `$AnotherJavaObject.toString()`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**

For anyone facing this same issue, the solution is within the Velocity Template Engine itself: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#parse

Instead of calling `load()` on the component with the *header* id, you just need to have

```
#parse("header.vm")
```

where you want the `header.vm` to be rendered.

You should use the `#include` directive to load static, non-Velocity templates like:

```
#include("other.html")
```

This is not this simple however. The documentation states that `#parse` and `#include` can only load resources from the **TEMPLATE_ROOT**. I was unable, however, to find out what that root is. So, on initialising the Velocity Engine, I had to enable this to accept relative paths:

```
properties.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.EVENTHANDLER_INCLUDE, IncludeRelativePath.class.getName());
velocityEngine = new org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine(properties);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't load it in JavaScript after template return results. you should use parse see [Velocity Loading resources](http://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/html/ch05s05.html):

```
#parse("header.vm")
```

And if you need to hide it use JavaScript to display/hide the results.